# Retrofit - Parallel HTTP requests

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an Android application that is currently using Retrofit library to make network requests. I have lots of parallel asynchronous requests. 
How can I now when all the requests are finished?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this post [Retrofit — Synchronous and Asynchronous Requests – Asynchronous Requests](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests#asynchronousrequests) which describes how to perform an HTTP call asynchronously by providing a callback.

You could use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) with a set `count` to wait until all invocations have finished, if you know beforehand how many calls you're going to perform.

Comment: That link asks me to login!

Comment: Sorry, but it was open back in Jan 2016.